# Substracting every nth element of a matrix from every ith element from another matrix

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices

```
A = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]
B = [w,x,y,z]
```

I want to substract like `[a,e,i]` from `w` and `[b,,f,j]` from `x` like that. 
All these letters are floats. The results will be in an array.

Could you assist how to substract every `n`-th element ofa matrix from every `i`-th element from another matrix?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to guess what you mean. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can first reshape your array to a 4×3 matrix, then subtract it, and then reshape it back. For example:

```
(A.reshape(-1, 4) - B).flatten()
```

For example:

```
>>> A
array([8, 7, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 4, 6, 8, 8, 1])
>>> B
array([7, 4, 2, 1])
>>> (A.reshape(-1,4) - B).flatten()
array([ 1,  3, -1,  3, -1, -2,  3,  3, -1,  4,  6,  0])
```